# How do I combine more than 5 PDFs with imagemagick convert?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using the following command to combine pdfs:

```
convert -density 300x300 -quality 100 ./1.pdf ./2.pdf ./merged.pdf"
```

The problem is when I give it a big list of pdfs (around 1000) to combine, it only combines the first 5. It doesn't raise any errors.

This isn't a difficult problem to circumvent. I can combine the pdfs in groups of 5 then combine those afterward. But I'm wondering if there's some `convert` configuration to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed just fine to put 100 PDFs together into one large one, but I am on OSX and the maximum length of the command-line is 262144 bytes. You can check yours with:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

To get around it, you could make **ImageMagick** read the list of PDFs to combine from a file so that you are not subject to the limit:

```
ls | grep "pdf$" > filelist.txt

convert @filelist.txt result.pdf
```

Comment: Sorry haven't tried it yet. Unfortunately my computer runs out of memory. I have a new computer coming Monday so I'll try it then